# At what temperature to bake waffles in a Lékuké silicon mold?

Tags: equipment, oven, waffle

We bought a Lékué silicon mold for waffles to be used in the oven, but the box in which we bought it does not mention the temperature at which to use it.

Can anyone having experience with baking waffles in an oven give us advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to reviewers on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008F4Z2K6) and this [video by Lékué](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gxsWzOzDiY), you should bake the waffles in an oven preheated to 220C (430F) for about 9 minutes. If the outside gets done before the inside, drop the temperature so you can bake longer. Other, more obscure sites and blogs say the same thing.

Did your box not include a recipe book?

Comment: Thanks. It came with a recipe, but even that does not mention a temperature. The package mentions 220C as the maximum temperature, which makes your answer even more probable..